# Visual Web Dev/ASP.net VB Button click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-web-developer

I'm having issues with a button click event and wondered if anyone can help?

Here's my asp code:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pcss3fs.css" />
    </head>
<body>
    <h1>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="57px" ImageUrl="~/img/logo.png" 
            Width="36px" />
        <strong>&nbsp;Test</strong> System </h1>

            <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="pcss3f">

            <header><asp:Label ID="lblOverview" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></header>

                <section class="state-normal" style="text-align:center">

                <button type="button" onclick="window.location = 'AddItem.aspx'">Add Work Item</button>
                <button type="button" id="btnMyWork" name="btnMyWork" onclientclick="btnMyWork_Click" runat="server">My Work Items</button>
                <button type="button">Database Stats</button>

                <br>
                </br>
                <asp:Label ID="lblWhoAmI" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                </section>



<footer><asp:Label ID="lblWhoAmI2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></footer>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The button I'm referring to is this:

```
<button type="button" id="btnMyWork" name="btnMyWork" onclientclick="btnMyWork_Click" runat="server">My Work Items</button>
```

And here's the VB I'm trying to get it to run:

```
Protected Sub btnMyWork_Click()
        lblOverview.Text = "Success"
        lblWhoAmI.Text = "Success"
    End Sub
```

But when I click it, nothing happens. I've tried adding a click handler in the aspx.vb code but the ".click" won't show in the IntelliSense.

Any help appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is a html button. You need to use the ASP button control to fire the `OnClick` event.
Something like below:

```
<asp:Button id="btnMyWork" onclick="btnMyWork_Click" runat="server" Text="My Work Items" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I'm getting a Runtime Error page now... If I take that out and put the old html code back it's OK. Can asp and html buttons run OK next to each other? Thanks

Comment: I've figured it out... the <form> needed a runat="server" as well. it's running fine now thanks for your assistance.